# Is there a sub-StackExchange for Widget questions?

Tags: discussion

Widgets are the new sub-Apps within the Flexmapping system by ESRI. I have questions about Widgets that I'm fairly certain would be a familiar topic for most GIS members here at StackExchange/Geographic Information Systems. Can I just ask these questions in the main forum or is there a specific location to ask them?

Answer (score 5):

According to our [help](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), such questions are on topic at GIS.

Answer (score 0):

If you are unsure whether anything is on-topic for GIS Stack Exchange that you wish to ask about, then often the best way to find out is by posting an exploratory Question or two on the topic.

You will soon see whether the community chooses to close them as off-topic, and if they do, and it seems to you unfairly so, then bringing your "case" here to Meta is a way to try and influence community opinions in the other direction.

In the case of widgets in the ArcGIS API for Flex, I suspect being on-topic would attract few dissenting opinions.